# MultiSelect(IEnumerable item, IEnumerable selected) doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I can't seem to figure this out.

I have these codes in my Controller

```
Entities db = new Entities();    

IQueryable<string> prod = db.Product.Where(p => p.Name != null)
            .Select(p => p.Name)
            .Distinct();

List<string> prodSelected = new List<string>() { "Pen", "Apple" };
ViewBag.ProductList = new MultiSelectList(prod, prodSelected);
```

And in the view, I have this line

```
@Html.ListBox("productList", ViewBag.ProductList as MultiSelectList, new { style = "width:160px", size = 1 })
```

Assuming the resulting "prod" up there is a list of strings:-

- "Pen"
- "Pineapple"
- "Apple"

When I run the code, why does the ListBox doesn't select the "Pen" and "Apple"? According to MSDN reference, I'm using MultiSelectList(IEnum items, IEnum selected). Shouldn't it work?

Or the (IEnum selected) there still refer to ID so I need to make a IEnumerable of IDs instead of string?

```
List<int> prodSelected = new List<int>() { 1, 3 };
```

Comment: rename ViewBag.ProductList , the variable which hold the selected value and the  variable  which provides the list of values should be different

Comment: mark the answer up :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to upvote a comment, but can't leave this question unanswered too.

Basically, as explained by Emil in the comment my mistake was having the variable that stored selected value and the one that provides the list having the same name, because caps don't matter in this case.